# react native drawer toggle is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

The drawerNavigator is in the stackNavigator.

I set the header to none, and I want to make the header part work when I press the button.

I wrote the following code.

> this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());

No error occurs. 
But it does not do anything.

The navigator code looks like this:

**navigator.js**

```
const MainScene = createStackNavigator({
 MainTab: {screen: MainTab},
 OtherScene: {screen: OtherScene}
},{...})

const OtherScene: createStackNavigator({
 DrawerScene: {screen: DrawerScene}
},{...})

const DrawerScene = createDrawerNavigator({
 Page1: {screen: Page1},
 Page2: {screen: Page2},
},{...})
```

**Header.js**

```
_sideMenu() {
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
}

render() {
  return (
   ...
   <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this._sideMenu()}>
    <Image ... />
   </TouchableOpacity>
   ...
  )
 }
```

Both page1 and page2 contain directly written headers.

**Page1.js**

```
render() {
 return(
  <View>
   <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />
   ...
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: have you tried `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()` instead?

Comment: An error occurs. **this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function.**

Comment: your redux configuration may be wrong. check using createAppContainer and createNavigationReducer.  RN 0.57.7 and react-navigation 3.x.

Answer (score 6):

try this 
import { DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());

Comment: This fix my error of  this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function.
The problem that i have right now is by default when you press the menu button instead of opening the drawer, it sends me to the homeScreen which is my first option. Not sure if this new problem is related or not but if anyone know the answer.. please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: @Zenit Have you specified the `initialRouteName` in the Drawer Navigator?

Answer (score 4):

One solution for this is to put the stackNavigator inside the drawerNavigation like so:

```
const MainScene = createStackNavigator({
 MainTab: {screen: MainTab},
 OtherScene: {screen: OtherScene}
},{...})

const OtherScene: createStackNavigator({
 SomeOtherScene: {screen: SomeOtherScene} // remove the drawer from here
},{...})

const DrawerScene = createDrawerNavigator({
 Page1: {screen: Page1},
 Page2: {screen: Page2},
 MainScene: {
     screen: MainScene, 
     navigationOptions: {
         drawerLabel: () => null
    }},
 OtherScene: {
     screen: OtherScene, 
     navigationOptions: {
         drawerLabel: () => null
    }},
},{initialRoute: "MainScene"})
```

This way you won't have issues with the open/close/toggleDrawer functions being undefined and you can even use them like so: this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();

If you don't want your "MainScene" and your "OtherScene" to appear in the drawer items just return null for their drawerLabels